# multiple foreach within foreach giving only one result

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to build the html divs in table layout from results in database.

I have sql table with positions for rows and sql table with content & positions for cells.
My code only gives the first result from the database...

`rowId`
`rowPos`
`latestRow`

---

`cellsRowId`
`cellsRowOrder`
`cellsContent`

```
$sql="SELECT `rowId` FROM `positions` ORDER BY `rowPos` ASC";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));}
  else{
   while ($pos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

    foreach($pos as $rowId){
        $sql="SELECT `cellsRowOrder` FROM `content` WHERE `cellsRowId` = '$rowId' ORDER BY `cellsRowOrder` ASC";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));}
        else{

         while ($order=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          foreach($order as $cellRowOrder){
             $sql="SELECT `cellsContent` FROM `content` WHERE `cellsRowId` = '$rowId' AND `cellsRowOrder` = '$cellRowOrder'";
             $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

             if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
             printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));}
             else{

             while ($cellsContent=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
             foreach($cellsContent as $cellContent){
                    echo '  
       <div class="content-layout-row" onmouseover="editButton'.$rowId.'()" onmouseout="editButtonClose'.$rowId.'()" id="r'.$rowId.'" >
        <div  id="editButton'.$rowId.'" style="visibility:hidden;width:100%;left:0;top:0px;z-index:2">
         <form method="POST" target="_top">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="'.$rowId.'"> 
          <input type="hidden" name="editRow" value="1">
          <button style="font-size:12px;border-radius:2px 5px 0px 0px" type="submit">edit</button>
         </form>
        </div>
        <div class="layout-cell" id="r'.$rowId.'s'.$cellRowOrder.'" >
         '.$cellContent.'
        </div>
       </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function editButton'.$rowId.'(){
         $("#editButton'.$rowId.'").css("visibility","visible"); 
        }
        function editButtonClose'.$rowId.'(){
         $("#editButton'.$rowId.'").css("visibility","hidden"); 
        }
        </script> ';
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 };
```

Comment: I didn't read much, but you're executing your query twice (`mysqli_query()`). That's unnecesarry. Check `$result` in the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT `cellsRowOrder` FROM `content` WHERE `cellsRowId` = '$rowId' ORDER BY `cellsRowOrder` ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

You are redefining `$result` half-way through a loop that is already using your earlier definition of `$result` as its condition.

All you need to do is rename your second `$result` to something else e.g. `$result2`

You are doing the same thing again here

```
$sql="SELECT `cellsContent` FROM `content` WHERE `cellsRowId` = '$rowId' AND `cellsRowOrder` = '$cellRowOrder'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Don't forget to rename them in all appropriate places, not just these lines.

Comment: Thanks that was a problem, also I've had while and foreach loops in wrong places - giving me multiple results.

Comment: I've spent some time reading around about mysqli_multi_query. My code works, but I don't like my self that I need to call multiple queries after each other to get right results. Can anyone verify that in my case mysqli_Multi_query would be appropriate and faster and why in few words?